# How to solve $T(n) = 3 T(n-1) + 10 T(n-2) + 7 \cdot 5 ^ n$?

Tags: recurrence-relation

Consider the recurrence
$$ T(n) = 3 T(n-1) + 10 T(n-2) + 7 \cdot 5 ^ n, $$
with base cases $T(0) = 4$ and $T(1) = 3$.

How do I solve such a recurrence?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S(n) = T(n)/5^n$. Then $S(0) = 4$, $S(1) = 3/5$, and
$$
S(n) = \frac{3}{5}S(n-1) + \frac{2}{5}S(n-2) + 7.
$$
Let $R(n) = S(n) - 5n$. Then $R(0) = 4$, $R(1) = -22/5$, and
$$
R(n) = S(n) - 5n = \frac{3}{5}R(n-1) + 3(n-1) + \frac{2}{5}R(n-2) + 2(n-2) + 7 - 5n = \\\frac{3}{5} R(n-1) + \frac{2}{5} R(n-2).
$$
We've reached a recurrence that we know how to solve. First, we need to find the roots of $x^2-(3/5)x-(2/5) = (x-1)(x+2/5)$. This shows that
$$
R(n) = A + \left(-\frac{2}{5}\right)^n B.
$$
Substituting the values of $R(0)$ and $R(1)$, we get $A+B = 4$ and $A-(2/5)B = -22/5$, and so $A = -2$ and $B = 6$. We conclude that
$$
T(n) = \left(6\left(-\frac{2}{5}\right)^n+5n-2\right)5^n = 5^{n+1}n - 2\cdot 5^n + 6(-2)^n.
$$